# grant select on x$mutex_Sleep. Как выдать?

Tags: sql, oracle

Не могу понять, как выдать грант на select из x$mutex_sleep.
Пробовал выдавать `grant select any table` и `grant select any dictionaries`, не помогло. Выдать грант явно так же не получается. Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему единственный вариант дать прямой доступ к `x$...` таблицам - это создать представление и дать доступ на него:

```
create view sys.my_x$mutex_sleep as select * from sys.x$mutex_sleep;
grant select on sys.my_x$mutex_sleep to username;
```

PS это может сделать только SYSDBA